# Xampp for Windows and Xampp for Linux different errors

Tags: php, mysql, linux, xampp

I wrote a piece of PHP code to get data from MySQL that is installed on Xampp. The code works fine on my windows Xampp but on Linux version of Xampp with the same code and database I get an error.
This is the code I wrote:

```
    <?php
     header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
     header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
     $conn = new mysqli("127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "", "company");
     mysql_select_db('company');

     $result = $conn->query("SELECT Emp_ID, First_Name, Last_Name, Salary, Project_ID FROM Employee ORDER BY Emp_ID");
     $outp = "[";
     $rows = array();



    $outp = "[";
    while($rs = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    if ($outp != "[") {$outp .= ",";}
    $outp .= '{"Emp_ID":"'  . $rs["Emp_ID"] . '",';
    $outp .= '"First_Name":"'   . $rs["First_Name"]        . '",';
    $outp .= '"Last_Name":"'. $rs["Last_Name"]     . '",';
    $outp .= '"Salary":"'. $rs["Salary"]     . '",';
    $outp .= '"Project_ID":"'. $rs["Project_ID"]     . '"}';
   }
   $outp .="]";
   $conn->close();
   echo($outp);


   ?>
```

On windows I get my JSON data as an output perfectly. On Linux I get the following error as an output:

```
   <br />
   <b>Fatal error</b>: Call to member function fetch_array() on a non-object in <b>/opt/lampp/htdocsdashboard/index.php</b> on line <b>14</b><br />
```

Like I said, I used the same database in PHPMyAdmin. I actually exported my database to SQL and imported it again in the Linux version.
Does anybody know what the problem is?

Comment: Case-sensitivity issue, may be. Check your table and column names here, `$result = $conn->query("SELECT Emp_ID, First_Name,...`

Comment: Thank you Rajdeep. It turned out to be a case sensitive error.